# Phone gap implementation of 'application settings'

Tags: android, cordova

I wanted to store some settings like username and password for my application, 
such that at the start of the application I would be able to do user authentication.

Can anyone guide me how to achieve this using **phoneGap**.

Comment: I think it's best to not store the password, just the username. Let the user enter their password and then store a authentication token (with whatever expiry: day, 3 months, 2 years). Store the username and auth token without the password. Do you think that's better?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
localStorage.setItem("pref1", "val1");

var pref1 = localStorage.getItem("pref1");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use phonegap local storage mechanism to achieve your tasks

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.1.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Answer (score 2):

You can use this plugin for Cordova 5.x
https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences

you add it

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-app-preferences
```

and then use it.

```
// cordova interface
var prefs = plugins.appPreferences;

function ok (value) {}
function fail (error) {}

// store key => value pair
prefs.store (ok, fail, 'key', 'value');

// store key => value pair in dict (see notes)
prefs.store (ok, fail, 'dict', 'key', 'value');
```

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that from IOS 5.1 (Apple) the local storage is temporary. If you want to write crossplatform applications it is better to use phonegap's FILE-api.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

Comment: Seems to be persistent with Phongap 3.3.0 on my iPad with iOS 7.1

Comment: Are the data in local store als persistent after updating the app?