# Phonegap with javascript global variable

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I am learning how to use phonegap now. I have a little bit experience in Android.

Since Android is Java-based, if we want to have global variable, we can simply define a static variable to handle it. So, we will be able to reference the static variable across all the activities in the app.

But phonegap is javascript-based, how am I going to create global variable that is able to be used across all the html pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript offers Local Storage.

Take a look at this answer: [Phone gap implementation of 'application settings'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845260/phone-gap-implementation-of-application-settings)

Comment: Is there any other way? Writing a whole global object into local storage seems strange.

Comment: localStorage is definitely the way to go. That's what it's made for.